# Sort out the data in different group and calculate the start time & end in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I did a performance test for cpu power and obtained a set of data in csv format. From the data, there're 5 different events and I want to sort out each event and calculate the start time & end time for each one. I tried to use Pandas in Python for this data analysis, however, I still have no clue how to do it. The following is the very basic code I've written so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import os, sys

df = pd.read_csv('new.csv')

col_Time = df[df.columns[0]]
col_Data = df[df.columns[1]]

## example_time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
## example_data_in_watts=[11.2, 10.3, 10.1, 21.2, 20.3, 22.1, 12.3, 10.7, 
##                        11.2, 23.6, 24.3, 25.1, 10.2, 11.3, 10.5]

## As above, each element in example_data_in_watts corresponds to element in 
## example_time. From this data, there're 2 events happened when the watts
## are ~21w and ~24w. My desired output will be to calculate the start & end 
## time for 21w & 24w, which are 3(sec) and 3(sec).
```

As you can see above, I only assign two variable to represent 2 different columns: one is for test time (unit: sec), the other is for the test data(unit: Watt). One way I can think of is probably use k-means method to sort out the event. But even if I do that, I am not sure if I can get the start time & end time from there?

If anyone knows how to sort out the events and calculate the start time & end time, please let me know. Appreciated a lot!!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you could include example input and desired output.

Comment: thx! :) I just included the example input and desired output in my codes above.

Answer (score 0):

From your example this seems as the easiest solution:

```
watts=[10,10,10,21,21,21,10,10,10,23,23,23,10,10,10]

result = {k : watts[:i+1].count(k) for i, k, in enumerate(watts) if k != 10}
```

**EDIT**

If you have floating data, and according to your example, here is what you can do:

```
watts=[10.2, 10.3, 10.1, 21.2, 21.3, 21.1, 10.3, 10.7, 10.2, 23.6, 23.3, 23.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.5]
watts = map(int,watts)

result = {k : watts[:i+1].count(k) for i, k, in enumerate(watts) if k != 10}
```

**EDIT OF EDIT**

Taking into account that the variation is **2.5** I think this can do the trick:

```
watts=[11.2, 10.3, 10.1, 21.2, 20.3, 22.1, 12.3, 10.7, 11.2, 23.6, 24.3, 25.1, 10.2, 11.3, 10.5]

watts = map(lambda x: x + x % 5, map(lambda x: x - x % 2.5, map(int, watts)))

result = {k : watts[:i+1].count(k) for i, k, in enumerate(watts) if k != 10}
```

Comment: Thanks! but the data set is actually much more complicated because the power differs a lot. So it'd be like from [10.1, 10.3, 10.2] and jump to [21.1, 21.4, 21.5] etc.

Comment: Thanks! :) But sorry that I still did not make the example clear.. Please check my edited codes above.  To be more specific, I'm wondering is there any way I can sort out of those two events(groups) and count how many seconds did each of them take? Because the amount of raw data is enormously huge, and the power actually have some small fluctuation on values.

Comment: Another workaround from my side, this is not proper way of doing it for sure, but it just might work :)

Comment: It still doesn't work tho... The codes gave me an error "TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable". I think it might be due to I'm using Python 3. Besides, I think I'll still need a more "proper way" for analyzing the data.